# Highcharts/stock - Change tooltip fontSize

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to define a larger `fontSize` for tooltip, but it only updates value tooltip, timestamp one keeps on default value. What option I should change? I cound't find anywhere on api.

[image]

Here is the [demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/bernardo0marques/0rdh5x23).

Answer (score 1):

The tooltip header has set inline font size by default:

```
'<span style=\"font-size: 10px\">{point.key}</span><br/>'
```

You can overwrite this value or remove it, then the header will inherit from tooltip style settings.

```
tooltip: {
  style: {
    fontSize: '18px'
  },
  headerFormat: '<span>{point.key}</span><br/>'
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8np2m5ua/

**API:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/tooltip.headerFormat

Comment: I'm not sure waht is different on my project but this approach didn't work.

Comment: Could you please share your configuration code then?